# python OOP, accessing attributes

Tags: python

Why do i get an "AttributeError: 'NewOne' object has no attribute 'self.b'" error message when i try to access the attribute 'self.b' from the NewOne class. I mean it's right there.

```
class NewOne(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 'Cat' # this is what i want to access
    def child(self):
        self.c = 'kitten'
        return self.c

class FatherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def son(self):
        self.i = 'I and my father'
        return self.i
    def father(self):
        self.x = 'are one'
        return self.x
    def father_son(self):
        u = NewOne()
        k = getattr(u, 'self.b') #why does it tell me NewOne has no self.b attr
        return self.a, k()
```

Isn't getattr used to access a method? Why is it called getattr and not getmeth or something?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace this:

```
k = getattr(u, 'self.b')
```

by this:

```
k = getattr(u, 'b')
```

or even better just do:

```
k = u.b
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! what happens if an attribute and a method have the same name?

Comment: An attribute and a method cannot have the same name. More precisely, a method *is* an attribute, just one that is callable.

Comment: you're very welcome, it get overwrite by the last one that get defined, try it and see :)

Answer (score 2):

Youe should write

```
k = getattr(u, 'b')
```

or better

```
k = u.b
```

instead.

The name of the attribute is `b`, not `self.b`.  And usually you access attributes via `obj.attr` -- the `getattr()` form is only needed if the name of the attribute is dynamic (i.e. not known at the time you write the code, but computed at run time).

Comment: "the getattr() form is only needed if the name of the attribute is dynamic" That's illuminating. Thank you.